# How does Kentico 12 Web Farm handle development and production sites with SAME domain name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico-12, kentico-api

Let's say I have a production MVC site called [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that uses Kentico 12 CMS.

To test certain functionality there are times when I need to setup a local development site to match the domain name [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) using the Windows hosts file. This is set up in local IIS.

How will Kentico web farm feature react to this? It has no way of telling whether this is production or not. Will this cause orphan tasks once the development site is shut down (or domain changed to dev.example.com)?

More importantly do I need to clear these orphan tasks after I'm done testing?

Comment: Is your local IIS set up using a local database or are you connecting to the live site database?

Comment: @Michael419 local IIS is set up to use live site database